# A question about application of the Ky Fan metric

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Q) Let $\alpha(X,Y) = \text{inf}\{\epsilon\geq 0: P(|X-Y|>\epsilon)\leq\epsilon\}$ be the Ky Fan metric and let $\beta(X,Y) = E(|X-Y|/1+|X-Y|)$. If $\alpha(X,Y) = a$, then prove that

$$a^2/(1+a)\leq \beta(X,Y)\leq a+(1-a)a/(1+a)$$ is what Durrett says but as obtained in the answer below, I think the upper bound should be $a+a[1-\frac{a}{1+a}]$

I am looking for a starting point. Appreciate a hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is standard that the infimum in the definition of the Ky-Fan metric is attained, that is $P(|X-Y|>a)\leq a$.
By definition of $a$, we have $b<a\implies P(|X-Y|>b)>b$.
Also, if $b\geq a$, $P(|X-Y|>b)\leq P(|X-Y|>a)\leq a$.

Let $\displaystyle f:x\mapsto \frac{x}{1+x}$. 
For the upper bound, 
$$\begin{aligned}
E(f(|X-Y|) &= \int_0^\infty P(f(|X-Y|)\geq t) dt \\
&= \int_0^{1} P(|X-Y|\geq \frac{t}{1-t}) dt\\
&\leq  \int_0^{a/(1+a)} 1 \; dt + \int_{a/(1+a)}^{1} a\; dt \\
&= \frac{a}{1+a} + a\left(1-\frac{a}{1+a}\right)\\
&=a+\frac{a(1-a)}{a+1}
\end{aligned}$$

For the lower bound, consider $\delta\in (0,a)$
$$\begin{aligned}
E(f(|X-Y|) &\geq E(f(|X-Y|)1_{|X-Y|>a-\delta})\\
&\geq f(a-\delta) P(|X-Y|>a-\delta)\\
&\geq f(a-\delta)(a-\delta)
\end{aligned}$$
Letting $\delta \to 0$ yields $\displaystyle E(f(|X-Y|)\geq \frac{a^2}{1+a}$, as wanted.

Comment: Thanks. A small correction, in the upper bound, the second term is $\int_{a/a+1}^{1}adt = a/(1+a)$.

Comment: @manifolded thanks for catching that. If you know that the Ky-Fan metric metrizes convergence in probability, then I guess the inequalities hint that $(X,Y)\mapsto E\left(\frac{|X-Y|}{1+|E-Y|}\right)$ also metrizes convergence in probability.

Comment: Neat trick for the lower bound as we know we have to setup $P(|X-Y|>a-\delta)$! Good observation about convergence in probability induced by the metric $E(\frac{|X-Y|}{1+|X-Y|})$ :)